# Hibernate add an entity with foreign key using REST

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, postman, dao

First of all, I haven't written any SQL statements to create a table. I try to use Hibernate/jpa only without writing SQL.

My relation is in the following: A user can have many task, a task only has one user.

I created my models as this:

User Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_USER")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private Long uid;
...
}
```

Task Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TASK")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TASK{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long tid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="oid")
    private User owner;

    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
...
}
```

The relation is task's ownerid(oid) is user's uid.

To save a user to my database, I'm using postman with the following parameters:

```
{
    "username": "firstuser",
    "email": "firstuser@email.com"
}
```

To save a task to my database I'm using this:

```
{
    "description": "some description",
    "oid": "12" // I also can state username of the user rather than ID
}
```

However, as I execute save a task, the oid of task is NULL. In data access objects, I have:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public QR createTask(@Valid @RequestBody Task task)
{
    return taskDAO.save(task);
}
```

1-What am I doing wrong? I just want to add a task with owner id to database, however it returns null as ownerid.

2-Should I create a table first with SQL using

```
 Create table task(
     tid BIGINT,
     description VARCHAR(255),
     oid BIGINT,
     PRIMARY KEY(tid), FOREIGN KEY(oid) REFERENCES (user.uid))
```

3-Should I change my save method in TaskDAO?

```
 public Task save(Task task)
 {
    return taskRepository.save(task);
 }
```

4- Should I change my controller method(createTask method using RESTcall)

5- Assume that all of the problems above is fixed. How can I fetch all task that a user has?

6- How can I delete a task when a user is deleted(cascase in SQL, but is there any method in Hibernate)

I hope I explained my problem. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `oid` is null because there is no such field in `Task`. I think you are mixing two concepts here. The first one is the data transfer object that represents your REST data structure. This one should have an oid field. The second one is the persisting entity. This one you have, it's the `Task` class.

I would implement a TaskDTO, use Hibernate's session to load the `User` by its id, then build a `Task` from the `User` and the other fields from `TaskDTO`, then save the Task like you do.

Regarding your other questions

2 - With a `create` or `update`value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, Hibernate can generate or update the tables when you start the application.

5 - You could have this interface

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public List<TaskDTO> getTasks(@PathVariable Long id)
```

Then I think you can't escape coding a criteria query of some sort.

6 - This is done with configuring the relation with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: I don't want to use **@GetMapping** and id in the url field. I implemented a dummy task transfer object, which is almost identical to task object, but it has 'oid' rather than user object. To use 'posttask' object in postmapping, If I understand clearly, I must convert it to an entity. I've found that I can use **convertToEntity** method but IntelliJ cannot find it. Possibly I must first add the dependency in pom.xml, then import it

Comment: You could certainly do that though I would advise you not to. In REST tradition, GET should be used when you retrieve data without changing anything in the system. POST on the contrary is the non-idempotent change. While it might seem clever on a short scale prototype, in a large scale application you definitely want you concepts (objects) to be aligned with some kind of perceived reality. As for convertToEntity, are you refering to the code in this article (https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) ?

Comment: Hmm. I though GET is used for getting information without changing anything on the backend server, POST is for creating an entity in the database(thus using body), PUT is for updating and DELETE self exploniatory.
As you stated, I'm referencing to that website for convertToEntity method. However, I'm not sure that it is good for my application. Whole reason why I use Spring is not to create an instance. But it creates a ModelMapper, I couldn't find Autowired entity of that

Comment: I do the same when translating HTTP verbs to CRUD operations. POST for creating is certainly a non-idempotent change (though not all non-idempotent changes are creations) :-). I am not a big fan of automatic mappers because they tend to shift simple problems (forgetting to map a property) to complex ones (why does this automatic thingy does not do what I want). I think it depends on the team you're working in / with. The reason for using Spring in the first place should be for dependency injection, then for great interfacing with technologies and protocols.

Comment: I have little knowledge about Spring and other facilities :)

I'm trying to learn new technologies and use them to increase my knowledge. Now, I have given up the ModelMapper mapper. I have created a taskDTO, and try to get information using getters and setters of taskDTO class, then find the user with that information.

Still, the code does not compile because it cannot find taskDTO. I have created taskDTO in the same folder with task, and used @Entity annotation at the beginning of the class. Also imported it in the Controller class. What should I do more?

Comment: `TaskDTO` should not be an entity. It's merely a simple Java object, that represents the received JSON payload. `Task` is the entity. The transaction should encompass converting TaskDTO to Task, then saving the task. It should look like this `User u = taskDAO.getUser(taskDTO.getOid()); Task t = new Task(taskDTO.getDescription(), u); taskDAO.save(t);`

Comment: Then, what is the purpose of using bean If I have to create a new Task object for that method?

Comment: Which bean do you mean? In a Spring app, everything is a bean :-). I am guessing you're dubious as to why there are two representations of the task. One is for transport, the other for persistence. JSON and the database row are also representations of the same data and very similar in terms of values. Without Hibernate / JPA you would do away with one Java representations ; it's the ORM layer that is responsible for that. Since your application seems so trivial (I mean no business logic involved), that overhead is clearly overkill.

Comment: When I say ***Task task = new Task();***, isn't that against whole purpose of the Spring? Shouldn't I never use new and let Spring handle those creations etc.

Comment: What you're referring to is a consequence of dependency injection with Spring. Broadly, in a Spring application, you declare the backbone of your application as beans without writing explicitly how things are wired together. There are multiple ways to do this. Task is not the backbone of your application. It defines no route, no transaction, no data access. It's just data. You can use new here.

Answer (score 0):

> 1-What am I doing wrong? I just want to add a task with owner id to database, however it returns null as ownerid

First of all, I would make sure that the owner is being persisted in the db, just to be sure that you have a value to be referencing

> 2-Should I create a table first with SQL using

Since you're using ORM, writing an SQL query would defeat the purpose of that, you could, but it's not all that necessary, since the relationships are specified already

> 3-Should I change my save method in TaskDAO?
>
> 4- Should I change my controller method(createTask method using RESTcall)

I think it would be best to change your createTask method, you could include the user's id as a pathvariable or a queryparameter and in that method you find the user using their id and set the user field in the task before passing it to the dto to save the value.
The reason the oid is null is because you do not have such a field in there.

> 5- Assume that all of the problems above is fixed. How can I fetch all task that a user has?

In your task repository, you can create a method like

```
Collection<Task> findAllTasksByOwnerId(Long id);
```

> 6- How can I delete a task when a user is deleted(cascase in SQL, but is there any method in Hibernate)

You can specify the cascade type where you have specified the relationship between the task and the user

[You can check this link for a simple tutorial on how to cascade in spring](https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and)

Answer (score 0):

```
The hibernate builds table and foreign keys automatically.Complex queries we can write in repo/controller in hibernate syntax.
With Crud repository we can delete , create update and read data easily.

    for example we have student to course one to many relation.

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "studentId", referencedColumnName = "studentId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<StudentCourses> studentCourses;

in StudentController I will write

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8090")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerStudentCourse",  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public StudentCourses registerStudentCourse(@RequestBody StudentCourses studentCourse) {
        if (studentCourse != null) {
            studentCourse.setLastupdated(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(new Date()));
            studentCourse = studentCourseRepository.save(studentCourse);
        }
        return studentCourse;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8090")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findStudentCourses",  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public List<StudentCourses> findStudentCourses(@RequestBody String studentId) {
        List<StudentCourses> courses = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject requestedJSONObject;
        try {
            requestedJSONObject = new JSONObject(studentId);
            String student = requestedJSONObject.getString("studentId");
            courses = 
 studentCourseRepository.findCoursesByStudent(Long.parseLong(student));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return courses;
    }
```